# How to GPG text on Unity?

Tags: unity, gnupg, seahorse

Once there was a Gnome-applet in Ubuntu (Seahorse?) which helped me with encryption/decryption of PGP text messages. It was able to encrypt or decrypt the clipboard.

Since Unity I have no idea, how to integrate this applet into my desktop. What is the recommended way to encrypt/decrypt text messages like emails or just some text from the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pyrite](https://github.com/ryran/pyrite) was written just for this purpose. It's not packaged yet -- so not in the repos; you'll have to follow a few instructions to download and extract it to a location of your choice manually, but it works wonderfully IMHO. (I would say that though.. since I'm the developer.)

As bessman mentioned, `seahorse-nautilus` is the way to go if you want to asymmetrically-encrypt files in the file browser. (In addition to text, `pyrite` can do symmetric & asymmetric encryption of files, but it's not integrated with Nautilus.)

Finally, check out [the answer on this older question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116996/how-do-i-encrypt-decrypt-file-within-gedit) for more details on setting up `gedit` with `gpg`.

Answer (score 4):

For email, there is a thunderbird addon called Enigmail which performs email encryption or signing, and is quite nicely integrated. Install it from the Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install enigmail`.

Seahorse still exists (it is called "Passwords and Keys" if you search in the dash), but does appear to have lost built-in support for text encryption/signing (I think - I don't have a GPG key on this system to test with).

This [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=680292) gives the syntax for signing, encrypting, verifying and decrypting text in the console with the `gpg` command.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116996/how-do-i-encrypt-decrypt-file-within-gedit) explains how to add gpg integration to `gedit`, although I must admit I was expecting to find better plugin support for encrypt/sign in both `gedit` and `tomboy` notes without obvious success.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate Seahorse with Nautilus by installing `seahorse-nautilus`. It will allow you to encrypt and decrypt files and folders by right-clicking them.