# trouble with gedit plugin

Tags: gedit, gnupg

I have been trying to replicate what has been suggested by Bruno Braga at the end of this thread:
[How do I encrypt/decrypt file within gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116996/how-do-i-encrypt-decrypt-file-within-gedit#218947)

I copied these two scripts and followed the instructions to the letter. But I had no joy as I get the 512 error. It says *gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input.*

The only thing I have changed is my email in the Encrypt script:

```
#!/bin/bash
stdin=$(cat)

if [ ! "${stdin:0:27}" == "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----"  ]; then 
     echo "$stdin" |   gpg -a -e -r elmclose@gmail.com --no-tty  -
else
    echo "$stdin"
fi


#!/bin/bash
stdin=$(cat)

if [ "${stdin:0:27}" == "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----"  ]; then 
    echo "$stdin" | gpg -d --no-tty - 2> /dev/null
else
    echo "$stdin"
fi
```

I have tested the command:

```
gpg -a -e -r elmclose@gmail.com test.txt
```

at the terminal and it works fine.
I have set the Input to "current document" and the output to "Replace current document"

What am I doing wrong?

I couldn't leave a comment at that thread as I have not enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The email address is not the only thing you modified. You also changed the shell from Bash to Bourne in the shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Change it to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The Bourne Shell doesn't support fancy Bash parameter substitutions like this: `"${stdin:0:27}"`

Comment: I changed /sh to  /bash and got this message:

gpg: 873E6BFC: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

 
and when I removed    --no-tty     the second message become:
gpg: cannot open tty `/dev/tty': No such device or address

In terminal mode I get the first message and I usually type yes and it finishes the job. But here it cannot receive an answer and drops out.
Is there a way I can supply the answer "yes" as part of the script? or is there something  else wrong with my script?

Comment: I don't know about GPG. You should [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/820984/edit) your question with the new info.