# why does this script fail?

Tags: gedit, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt in gedit using the "Manage External Tools"
The script is from this thread:
[How do I encrypt/decrypt file within gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116996/how-do-i-encrypt-decrypt-file-within-gedit#218947)

```
#!/bin/bash
gpg -d --no-tty - 2> /dev/null
```

and the error is:

> gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

[image]

Comment: Use text instead of image to show scripts, errors etc.

Comment: If you want to debug something, do not discard error messages. Never. The error message will very likely explain the issue.

Comment: Change the "/dev/null" in your script to "~/myerrorlog.txt" and post the contents in your question after you tried again.

Comment: the error message is : [  gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input] -- this is of course true as I am expecting to get asked for the passphrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gpg2 --decrypt --no-tty $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
```

It is necessary to use gpg2 as command instead of gpg. So you will receive the prompt from the gpg-agent / pinetry to decrypt the text. The 2.nd missing part was to get the filename of the current document which ist determined by the $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME-Environment-Variable.

Picture: [gedit with gpg decrypted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh1IY.jpg)

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools

Comment: Thank you very much Mick, it worked. I was beginning to despair. I removed the environment variable option as gedit picks up all that info from the script definition dialog box. Someone should tell the original contributors I mentioned at the top of my post about this? I tried but was told I had not enough reputation to comment. Thanks again friend, you made my day.

Comment: good to hear that i could help you  ;-) I think the tags below your first post ,could  be helpful to  someone who's searching for a similar solution and get maybe a hint in the "related" section on the right of this page. Have a nice week.